# How to render markdown file into a webpage in Jekyll?

Tags: html, localhost, markdown, jekyll

I just installed Jekyll on my local and trying to get familiar with it.

I just cloned a whole folder structure from github with markdown files and yaml files inside, and the whole folder structure is inside my Jekyll folder. Did I do it right? How should I be able to convert the markdown files to html files by using Jekyll? How should I do it? Very confused now and stuck.

Comment: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/

Answer (score 1):

Create the '_layouts' directory in the root of your Jekyll installation. Create a 'default.html' file in this newly created directory. Add `{{ content }}` to the content of this new file. Change the markdown file (index.md)  to:

```
---
layout: default
---
Hello world!
```

Go to localhost:4000 and when in doubt look at this: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure

PS. You might also need an (empty) '_config.yml' file in the root of your Jekyll installation, because this is where Jekyll gets its configuration from.

Comment: Thank you! I'm wondering what if I got a whole folder structure from Github, then how should I render the md files from that folder structure into html by using Jekyll?

Comment: I do not know what 'a whole folder structure' is. Please be more specific.